# Why I can't log in with the correct password?

Tags: linux, login

```
Apr  6 01:05:11 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1108]: Failed to create inotify watch on /var/run/utmp, ignoring: No space left on device
Apr  6 01:05:11 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1108]: New session c2 of user prosec.
Apr  6 01:05:11 ASUS-tek systemd: pam_limits(systemd-user:session): wrong limit value 'hard' for limit type 'hard'
Apr  6 01:05:11 ASUS-tek systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user prosec by (uid=0)
Apr  6 01:05:11 ASUS-tek lightdm: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly and unlocked keyring
Apr  6 01:05:11 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1108]: Session c2 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Apr  6 01:05:12 ASUS-tek lightdm: pam_limits(lightdm-greeter:session): wrong limit value 'hard' for limit type 'hard'
Apr  6 01:05:12 ASUS-tek lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Apr  6 01:05:12 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1108]: Failed to create inotify watch on /var/run/utmp, ignoring: No space left on device
Apr  6 01:05:12 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1108]: New session c3 of user lightdm.
Apr  6 01:05:12 ASUS-tek lightdm: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
Apr  6 01:05:13 ASUS-tek lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): incomplete condition detected
Apr  6 01:05:21 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1108]: Removed session c1.
Apr  6 01:05:24 ASUS-tek dbus-daemon[1050]: [system] Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_timeout=25000ms)
Apr  6 01:05:25 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1108]: Power key pressed.
Apr  6 01:05:25 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1108]: Powering Off...
Apr  6 01:05:25 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1108]: System is powering down.
Apr  6 01:05:25 ASUS-tek lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
Apr  6 01:07:39 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1100]: Failed to create inotify watch on /var/run/utmp, ignoring: No space left on device
Apr  6 01:07:39 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1100]: New seat seat0.
Apr  6 01:07:39 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1100]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Lid Switch)
Apr  6 01:07:39 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1100]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event1 (Power Button)
Apr  6 01:07:39 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1100]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event5 (Logitech USB Receiver Consumer Control)
Apr  6 01:07:39 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1100]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (AT Translated Set 2 keyboard)
Apr  6 01:07:49 ASUS-tek lightdm: pam_limits(lightdm-greeter:session): wrong limit value 'hard' for limit type 'hard'
Apr  6 01:07:49 ASUS-tek lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Apr  6 01:07:49 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1100]: Failed to create inotify watch on /var/run/utmp, ignoring: No space left on device
Apr  6 01:07:49 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1100]: New session c1 of user lightdm.
Apr  6 01:07:49 ASUS-tek systemd: pam_limits(systemd-user:session): wrong limit value 'hard' for limit type 'hard'
Apr  6 01:07:49 ASUS-tek systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user lightdm by (uid=0)
Apr  6 01:07:50 ASUS-tek lightdm: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
Apr  6 01:07:51 ASUS-tek lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): incomplete condition detected
Apr  6 01:07:53 ASUS-tek systemd-logind[1100]: System is rebooting.
Apr  6 01:07:53 ASUS-tek lightdm: pam_unix(lightdm-greeter:session): session closed for user lightdm
```

---

I had and have enough of free space.

Recovery mode:

```
root@ASUS-tek:~# df
df: /root/.cache/doc: Operation not permitted
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             7809992         0   7809992   0% /dev
tmpfs            1576896      1596   1575300   1% /run
/dev/nvme1n1p5 134229752  25579448 101758940  21% /
tmpfs            7884460         0   7884460   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            7884460         0   7884460   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/nvme1n1p4  57819156  10605124  44244536  20% /var
/dev/nvme1n1p3  19509484    918652  17574464   5% /boot
/dev/nvme1n1p2   9740796        96   9224300   1% /tmp
/dev/nvme1n1p6 255619604 129112864 113449204  54% /home
/dev/loop0           384       384         0 100% /snap/bpytop/256
/dev/nvme1n1p1    997456      6196    991260   1% /boot/efi
/dev/loop1           128       128         0 100% /snap/bare/5
/dev/loop2         93952     93952         0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1535
/dev/loop3         88064     88064         0 100% /snap/session-desktop/275
/dev/loop4           384       384         0 100% /snap/bpytop/261
/dev/loop5        224256    224256         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-34-1804/77
```

I added fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576 to sysctl.conf and result unchanged. This happened after a system update. Something must have overwritten the config file maybe ?

Comment: maybe https://askubuntu.com/questions/994127/cant-login-ubuntu-but-can-ssh-to-it

Answer (score 1):

```
lightdm: pam_limits(systemd-user:session): wrong limit value 'hard' for limit type 'hard'
```

In `/etc/security/limits.conf` file, or in any `/etc/security/limits.d/*.conf` file, there seems to be a typo.

In the resource limit configuration files, each non-empty non-comment line should have four fields:

- domain to which the limit should apply: either `username`, `@groupname`, or the wildcard `*` (special case: also `%` and `%groupname` for the `maxlogin` limit)
- limit type: `soft` or `hard`
- limit item: the name of the limit you're planning to assign
- limit value: usually a number

The error message suggests there is a line that has the word `hard` in the 4th field (limit value), which would be incorrect.

Perhaps the malformed line causes the corresponding limit to be set to 0 or some other extremely restrictive value, which will cause the session to fail?

If so, then the error message `Failed to create inotify watch on /var/run/utmp, ignoring: No space left on device` might actually be caused by hitting the incorrectly-set resource limit.

```
lightdm: pam_succeed_if(lightdm:auth): incomplete condition detected
```

This suggests there might be a typo, truncation or some other form of corruption in the `/etc/pam.d/lightdm` file, or one of the files it refers to using the `@include` statement. The error seems to be on one of the `auth` lines.

See `man pam_succeed_if` [or here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/pam_succeed_if) for a description of the correct syntax. Briefly, a *condition* should be a group of three words: a field name, a test, and a value to test for.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error caused by reaching the calling limit of the inotify service, which is being used by systemd. You can increase the calling limit of the inotify service by using the following command:

```bash
sysctl fs.inotify.max_user_watches=1048576
```

https://github.com/google/cadvisor/issues/1581#issuecomment-367616070

However, you are unable to enter the shell, you can boot from a USB memory containing the OS image, mount the disk you have been using, and chroot to it to execute the above command.

Answer (score 0):

The key error is

> No space left on device

You’ve run out of disk space, which is preventing you from logging in.

You need to boot in recovery mode and free up some disk space.